# How to get the latest record from a database in ASP.Net using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to get the latest record from my **database**

**Below is my query**

```
select * from tablename order by date desc, time desc
```

**My Issues**
My query show uncertain behavior, sometimes it works properly in website but sometimes is does not give the desired result. It happen because of time part

**Example**

**2:00 pm and 2:00 AM how to compare this time?**

Comment: your columns are datatype "TIME" and "DATE" not varchar?

Comment: Why dont you have a single column of `DATETIME` and order it?

Comment: What are the types of your date and time columns? The only reason for your query not working properly is if your date and time columns are not of types date and time but of type varchar. If this is a case the problem is with your database design rather than your query.

Comment: If you are using proper date structures then the date is stored as a number with the time being a decimal, this means that 2AM equates with 2/24 and 2PM with 14/24, which the query will never confuse. so you must be using the wrong types

Comment: Additionally to the above, if you have an id column where most recently inserted record is highest id then simply `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score 3):

The exact Query is for getting very latest row

```
 select Top 1 * from tablename order by date desc, time desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Convert the date and time into a datetime and then order by that.

```
select * 
from tablename 
order by cast(date AS DATETIME) + cast(time AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: if they are storing the time as text in 12h format with out he AM PM indicator  then they have lost the ability to convert back, which is what the question indicates is the problem they're having is

Comment: But @MikeT that would be just display presentation, no? Nasik Best Programmer, these are times, not string, correct? [Edit: I see some comments on the main post also about this. Waiting for answer]

Comment: if you are using the proper structures as the base storage you are correct, you can then take the raw data that is hidden from the user and display it in what ever format you wish, however if you are storing the the text in a text base format then it has to try and defermine automatically what the underlying value should have been which means that 2:00 will always be 2AM and never 2PM, which is the problem he states in the question

Answer (score 2):

so if you´re datatype is really VARCHAR you can convert it to date and time in the order by clause

```
begin
declare @time1 time
declare @time2 time

declare @test table(
    mytime varchar(max),
    mydate varchar(max)
)

insert into @test VALUES('2:00 pm', '10-10-2010')
insert into @test VALUES('2:00 am', '08-05-2009')

SELECT * FROM @test ORDER BY CONVERT(date, mydate) DESC, CONVERT(time,  mytime) DESC

end
```

but i would suggest to change your table-structure, to have only one DateTime Column!
Or at least change the DataType to TIME and DATE!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have some special requirement, it will be better to use only one column of `datetime` type to store date and time.

If two columns are must, you can store time in 24-hour format.

Comment: I've seen many instances where keeping the date and time sperate are a requirement, usually when they are required for indexes, as you can't index by calculation very easily do. so if you need to query by just the date and not the time, you void the benefits of using the index by combining the fields

Answer (score 2):

```
 Select Top 1 ColumnName from dbo.TableName Order by date,time desc
```

Comment: this doesn´t order by time, at least in his current Table-Structure

Comment: Thanks but time problem still occur... only because of time latest record not able to fetch

Comment: @NasikBestProgrammer : I still cnt understand ur problem. Provide a sample date which appears in ur table.

Comment: Example Table Name is abc in that 2 field is there time and date i want latest record date format is mm/dd/yy and time format is set in 12 hour like AM and PM. I want latest Record mean top 5 record

Comment: First, ahy u storing time separately.? when you have datetime as a datatype. If you are having 2 columns then above edit by @Waqas is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should convert the time in AM/PM to 24-hrs format. Check this out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format